# Spring SOAP Web-сервис генерация нескольких fault'ов в wsdl

Tags: java, spring, xsd, веб-служба, wsdl

Создал тестовый веб сервис наподобие вот этого туториала - http://spring-projects.ru/guides/producing-web-service/. Сгенерировал wsdl, все ок.

Интересует такая штука - могу ли я к одной операции прикрепить несколько фолтов? Сейчас он один - getStudentFault.

**students.xsd**

```html
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://concretepage.com/soap"
           targetNamespace="http://concretepage.com/soap" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="getStudentRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="studentId" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="getStudentResponse">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="student" type="tns:student"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="getStudentFault">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element  minOccurs="0" name="StudentFault" nillable="true" type="tns:student"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="student">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="studentId" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="class" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    
</xs:schema>
```

**StudentEndpoint**

```
@Endpoint
public class StudentEndpoint {
  private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://concretepage.com/soap";
  @Autowired
  private StudentUtility studentUtility;

  @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getStudentRequest")
  @ResponsePayload
  public GetStudentResponse getStudent(@RequestPayload GetStudentRequest request) {
      GetStudentResponse response = new GetStudentResponse();
      response.setStudent(studentUtility.getStudent(request.getStudentId()));
      return response;
  }

}
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы после генерации wsdl было несколько фолтов у операции.